# How to connect to database with Node JS using Cordova framework?

Tags: node.js, cordova

I am totally new in creating apps in js and don't know to connect app to the PostgreSQL database.

I saw that SQLite can use but if only I download data from table to local machine and send it to app but I want to have connection to db online from app, I want to let user register and login.

I have a html page with login button:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" id="login" class=" second" name="login" placeholder="login">
    <input type="text" id="password" class=" third" name="login" placeholder="password">
    <input type="submit" class=" fourth" id="loginbtn" value="Log In">
</form>
```

and button.js where I want to store some data into db:

```
const { Client } = require('pg')
const client = new Client({
    user: 'host',
    host: 'pecs.postgres.database.azure.com',
    database: 'table',
    password: 'password',
    port: 5432,
})

document.getElementById("loginbtn").addEventListener('click',register);
function register() {

    alert("e")

    client.query(
        "INSERT INTO clients(id, password, username)VALUES(1, 'danik', 'danik')",
        (err, res) => {
            console.log(err, res);
            alert(err)
            client.end();
        }
    );

}
```

I guess I have to use webService.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out , I created another express application where connected to database with pool and made endpoint to communicate with db , in Cordova application used simple Fetch API.

Comment: I know this is like a year later, but I am just starting with Cordova. So you cannot actually write node.js code within the Cordova project? I need to Create a separate application that hosts the backend code, and then fetch the url that hosts the code, and it should work? I am so confused on what to do, if you could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it!

Comment: @gianlps Yeah i had to create another app in node.js for backend with rest services and this app has to be tuned on. Here sample project for server, hope it can help https://gitlab.com/Danik7182/serverfortimetable/-/tree/master